# Process not triggered by Import

Tags: process-builder, import, data-import-wizard

We built a process which auto populates a text field when three other text fields have certain values. It work fine when I change values manually, but not when I update the fields with the Data Import Wizard. Is there any chance I can trigger the process in a different way?

Comment: Is the setting "Trigger workflow rules and processes?" active in the Data Import Wizard?

Comment: Also note from documentation - [Import Data with the Data Import Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&type=5) - `If you have workflows that add new objects when importing, selecting add new and update existing records fires them, but selecting update existing records doesn't.`

Comment: I did not expect that the solution was that easy and there all the time...Thanks David!